# Python data structure for thesaurus

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I need to have synonyms that I define for about 100 words of my of my choice. For testing I am adding the entries manually:

```
t = {}
t.update({'Strong':['Strong', 'Able', 'Active', 'Big',
                    'Energy', 'Firm',
                    'Force', 'Heavy', 'Robust', 'Secure',
                    'Solid', 'Stable', 'Steady',
                    'Tough', 'Vigor', 'Might',
                    'Rugged', 'Sound']})

t.update({'Fast':['Fast', 'Agile', 'Brisk', 'Hot', 'Quick',
              'Rapid', 'Swift', 'Accel', 'Active',
              'Dash', 'Flash', 'Fly', 'Race', 'Snap',
              'Wing', 'Streak', 'Time', 'Chop', 'Jiffy',
              'Split', 'Bat', 'Crazy', 'Double', 'Scream',
              'Sonic', 'Super', 'Ball', 'Speed']})
```

So I am creating an empty dictionary, and then taking words like "Strong" and "Fast" and mapping it to synonyms (which I need to be able to choose).

Since I need only 100 different word mappings is this a reasonable approach? Or is there a better way to implement this?

I am also looking at using NLTK and the wordnet module. However, this module takes awhile to run and it seems I have no way of adding synonyms like I need.

Comment: Are you getting this data form somewhere (a file, a web service, etc) you can parse ti from?

Comment: Thesaurus uses some kind of weighted values for synonyms, but I guess that is not necessary, so a `dict` with a `key` and a list of synonyms as `value`s should be a good way of doing it. The only problem is that you add that manually, so it is no scalable

Comment: I am not getting the data from anywhere at the moment, although it could be a possibly to set it up this way. Weighted values is an interesting idea, but I do not need that at the moment... something that would scale would be ideal as even entering 100 manually is going to take a long time.

Comment: Not sure what format your data is in, but you could enter all the data into an Excel sheet, save it as a csv, then open the file and load line-by-line into your dict data structure with a very simple python script.

Comment: I would definitely use the internet for this one, you could likely use thesaurus.com, the python requests library, and BeautifulSoup pretty easily

Comment: Oh good idea, I was just learning about beautiful soup this morning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an actual thesaurus, individual words may belong to multiple sets of synonyms.  For example, *fast* as in *quick* might be one list while *fast* as in *secure* might be in another.

I would map each word to a list of "sense groups," and then each sense group would map to a list of words.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, {'Fast': 'QuickGroup', 'SecureGroup'... etc.} and then {'QuickGroup': 'agile', 'brisk', 'rapid'... etc.} ?

Answer (score 2):

I could organize your thesaurus in a `graph` fashion. First of all, you keep all the words in a dictionary `word -> key` and then you make a **linked-list** graph, since it will be sparse.

```
w = {}
w = {'Fast': 0, 'Strong': 1, 'Able': 2, 'Active': 3, 'Big': 4, ...}

t = {0: [1, 2, 3, ...], ...}
```

It would scale better for large data sets, since **ints** use less memory than **strings**.